# Data visualization in the terminal?

Tags: visualization, linux

I've gotten to love using the terminal for processing data. At work, I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). For school and personal, I'm using Linux terminal on a Google Cloud instance.

I love how quick I can move files and code around in the terminal and using Vim editor. I love the minimalism of text directories, etc. The major downside is I haven't been able to use charts, like matplot or seaborne, because I'm in a terminal.

Is there a solution, other than copying files and code over to something like Jupyter? I can write modules to plot basic bar charts in the terminal, but I obviously need more than that.

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib and Seaborn are graphical plotting libraries, there is no straightforward way to display data visualizations in the terminal.

The best option is to run Jupyter Notebook with `--no-browser` flag on the remote instance. Then, paste the URL from the remote instance in your local computer browser. You make have make sure the ports and permissions are correctly set. Connecting to a remote Jupyter server from a local computer allows plotting on the remote instance.

Comment: Thanks. And I believe that implies I set up a GUI on my Google Cloud instance? Which has been on my to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [libsixel](https://github.com/saitoha/libsixel). I know that the [fast.ai](https://twitter.com/jeremyphoward/status/1104248904000856064) library uses it to plot on the terminal.